# Help with using a while loop and if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to write a program that reads 2 numbers from the user and divides them. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class divideByZero {

public static int quotient(int numerator, int denominator)
{
   return numerator / denominator;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the first number: ");

    int numerator = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");

    int denominator = scanner.nextInt();

    int result = quotient( numerator, denominator );

    float result2 = (float)result;

    System.out.printf("\n The first number %d divided by the second number "
            + "%d = %f\n", numerator, denominator, result2 );

}
```

How can I change it so that it is a while loop, using an if statement to check the second number and if it is 0, ask the user to input a different number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an answer to your question, but you need to convert at least one of those numbers to a double. Right now you'll just be doing integer division, i.e. 5/3 = 1. You can do this with double num = (double) denominator.

Second, this is a good use of a do while loop. Keep asking for the number until it isn't a 0. You know you want a do while loop when your first iteration through the loop doesn't have a condition (i.e. you know you'll be doing the logic AT LEAST once.)

```
System.out.println("Please enter the second number: ");
do {
     int denominator = scanner.in();
     if (denominator == 0) System.out.println("Please enter a non-zero number: ");
} while (denominator == 0);
```

Comment: +1 for "You know you want a do while loop when your first iteration through the loop doesn't have a condition."  That is the clearest I've heard it expressed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Where would I change it to double? I've tried, but keep getting a "method quotient in class cannot be applied to given types" error.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a full understanding of types yet. I don't want to just give you an answer, so how can I give a hint... um, here's some info on casting: http://www.fluffycat.com/Java/Casting/

Comment: Would it look something like this? float result2 = (float)result;

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'm having trouble with the actual computations now. For example, when I enter 3 divided by 4, I'm getting the result 0.000000.

Comment: haha, it's hard to do this discussion in the comments. Can you show your updated code in an edit?

Comment: There are a few issues here. You might want to start a new question. Here's one example: int result = quotient( numerator, denominator ); You've specified result as an int! How do you expect it to store a non-integer, like the answer to 3/4?

Answer (score 3):

```
int denominator = 0;
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");
    denominator = scanner.nextInt();
} while (denominator == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");
int denominator = scanner.nextInt();
while (denominator == 0) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a non-zero number: ");
    denominator = scanner.nextInt();
}
```